# How can I make two ListViews scroll together in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have two ListViews side by side, and I have the scrollbar hidden on one of them. Is there any easy way to make it so that if I scroll the one with the scrollbar, the other one will automatically follow?

I thought I might be able to bind the properties together, but I can't seem to find any scrollbar-position type property on the ListViews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the `ScrollBar` out of the both the ListViews and **bind** their `valueProperty`.

Example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        // Declare ListView's
        ListView listView1 = new ListView<String>();
        ListView listView2 = new ListView<String>();

        // Fill Data inside ListView
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            list.add("Value " + i);
        }
        listView1.setItems(list);
        listView2.setItems(list);

        root.getChildren().addAll(listView1, listView2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Bind the ListView scroll property
        Node n1 = listView1.lookup(".scroll-bar");
        if (n1 instanceof ScrollBar) {
            final ScrollBar bar1 = (ScrollBar) n1;
            Node n2 = listView2.lookup(".scroll-bar");
            if (n2 instanceof ScrollBar) {
                final ScrollBar bar2 = (ScrollBar) n2;
                bar1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(bar2.valueProperty());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```